# error while compiling speech_tools can not find -lcurses

Tags: gcc, ncurses

I get the following error when compiling speech_tools.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [ch_lab] Error 1
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

It can't find `-lcurses`

Comment: Please leave a comment if my answer is not correct (can not test your problem here so it is partly a guess ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes ,it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably means you need to install lncurses (package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/quantal/libncurses5-dev)

So ...

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: If cross-compiling 32-bit on a 64-bit system, use `lib32ncurses5-dev`